# In C, During mathematical operation, why does float behave differently when it is in a variable

Tags: c

So heres an example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int score1 = 70, score2 = 58, score3 = 99;

    float total = 3;
    printf("Average: %f\n", (score1 + score2 + score3)/total);
}
```

and it gives me `75.666664`. whereas if I replace total with just 3.0 like this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int score1 = 70, score2 = 58, score3 = 99;
    printf("Average: %f\n", (score1 + score2 + score3)/3.0);
}
```

it gives me `75.666667.`

Comment: 3.0 is a double, not a float. So you are performing a division of doubles instead of floats

Comment: @Raildex I thought the division would promote the float to a double?

Comment: @julaine the first snippet is a float (because total is a float) division, the second is a double division

Comment: @Raildex I realize that, but I thought that using a float and an int in an operation would promote both operands to double, since that is the datatype that can hold values of both. But it seems like I hallucinated that rule, I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Float is only promoted to double if you're combining it with a double. Here you're dividing `int` by `float`, so the `int` is converted to `float`. Nothing gets converted to double.

Comment: @julaine [there's only integer promotion and no floating-point promotion in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion). `float` just underwent  default argument promotions in variadic functions like `printf`

Comment: @Barmer it seems like you are right. I would have hoped it gets promoted to double because that would be a true promotion with no rounding. But C doesn't work that way, and also, my line of thinking assumes int==32bits, float==32bits and double==64bits which the standard doesnt mandate.

Comment: but why does it affect the answer? is it because it has to do with the bytes each data represents? like isnt 3.0 in float and 3.0 in doubles the same?

Comment: @phuclv As we can see from that link, there is plenty of floating point promotion in C... did you read it yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in C has a type and that includes numeric constants/literals such as `3.0`.

- `3` has type `int`.
- `3.0f` has type `float`.
- `3.0` has type `double`.

And in turn, `float` and `double` may or may not have the same precision on a certain system. Apparently `double` has higher precision on your system and therefore you notice a difference.

---

Some notes regarding [implicit type promotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules):

- `score1 + score2 + score3` are all of type `int` so no implicit promotions take place and the result is `int`.
- This result `int` placed together in an operation with another operand of type `float`, means that the `int` will get promoted to `float` before the operation (as per "the usual arithmetic conversions", see the above link).
- Or in case of `3.0`, the `int` result would have been promoted to `double`.
- `printf` and `%f` do as it happens always expect a `double` as input (`%lf` will work too), and in case you hand it a `float`, it will get implicitly promoted to `double` by an oddball rule for variadic functions called "the default argument promotions".

  But since this final type promotion happens *after* the result was calculated, it doesn't affect the precision.

---

Best practices:

- Be explicit about types and avoid code containing silent implicit promotions.
- Avoid mixing `int`/`float`/`double` in the same expression, since that's a well-known recipe for bugs. Stick to one type and explicitly cast operands where needed.

For example I would rewrite your code like this:

```
(double)(score1 + score2 + score3) / 3.0
```

The functionality is 100% equivalent, but this is self-documenting code without reliance on implicit promotion saying "I know what I'm doing".

The opposite - code relying on silent implicit promotions - says: "Either I know what I'm doing and rely on implicit promotion, or I don't know what I'm doing and just got this expression right/wrong by (bad) luck".

Comment: Newbie question here but, %f expects a double as input. How about for float? What %(letter) will expect a float

Comment: @Aces `%f` as well. And yeah that doesn't make sense, but these old rotten libs like stdio.h rarely do. At some point in the dinosaur ages they probably only had support for one floating point type, then later added support for another. Hence the need for the mentioned "default argument promotions" turning `float` into `double` when pased to printf, so that `%f` works for both types. `%lf` was added far later and only for consistency with `scanf`, which always made a difference between `%f` = `float` and `%lf` = `double`.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you always use  `%f` for `float` and `%lf` for `double`, and use a moden C compiler, then you can never go wrong.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't.

Your first example divides the sum by a 32bit float 3.0f and computes the closest approximation to 227/3.0f that single precision floating point computation can represent.

Your second example divides the sum by an (implicit) 64bit double 3.0 and gets the closest approximation to 227/3.0 that double precision can represent.

The distinction would be much clearer if you printed it with a format %26.18g.

I suggest that you put 75.666666666666666666666 into the decimal to binary website [Base Convert IEEE754](https://baseconvert.com/ieee-754-floating-point) to see how this works in practical binary FP representations under IEEE754.

Incidentally many modern optimising compilers will translate dividing by a constant at **compile** time into multiplying by precomputed reciprocal constant value  "1.0f/3.0f" because it is much quicker than divide. Check the assembler listing to see if that is the case with your compiler.